# Eclipse vs Netbeans Maven Folder Structure

Tags: eclipse, maven, netbeans

I am using Maven in Eclipse and Netbeans and I notice that the Maven folder structure is quite different from each other respective of each IDE.

Understanding that the standard folder structure is:
src
target
pom.xml

How can I make Netbeans follow the same structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that the default maven structure is `src/target/pom.xml` itself is wrong.
The default folder structure four your source files is `src/main/java` and for resources files is `src/main/resources`. 
If you have static contents such as html and javascript files then they go in `src/main/webapp` folder.

See this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for more details.

Your IDE (be it Eclipse or Netbeans) has (and should not) **NO** control on how the folder structure appears when you import/create a maven project on the IDE. Rather it is controlled by Maven.

The IDE will simply display the folder structure as it is currently present.
Reorganize your folder structure based on the link I gave above and you should be good to go then.

Answer (score 0):

I use Netbeans and I am having the same problem while learning from a project that is written in Eclipse. In Eclipse, why is there another folder "Java Resources"? should not all the source files be in - `src/main/java` and resources files in - `src/main/resources`?

Why use the folder `Java Resources` to write source files.